# Package acro: How to increase line space between acronym entries

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, acronyms, vertical-spacing, acro

I am using the package acro for listing acronyms in my paper. It has no compatibility issues with my document class memoir, and is very easy to use. But, the default line space between acronym entries is too small, the acronym page look quite crowded. How to increased it?

If there is a long entry, the line space within an entry is OK as it is.

Below is the test code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{acro} %list of abbreviations
\acsetup{first-style = long-short, list/display = used}

\DeclareAcronym{acm}{ 
    short = {ACM}, 
    long  = {Association for Computing Machinery}
}
\DeclareAcronym{ieee}{
    short = {IEEE},
    long  = {Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers}
}

\DeclareAcronym{owasp}{ 
    short = {OWASP}, 
    long  = {the Open Web Application Security Project}
}

\DeclareAcronym{iso}{ 
    short = {ISO}, 
    long  = {International Organization for Standardization}
}

\DeclareAcronym{cicd} {
    short = {CI/CD}, 
    long = {the combined practices of continuous integration and continuous delivery or continuous deployment}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Showcases of acro Acronyms}

\ac{ieee} is an organization.
\newline
\ac{acm} is another organization.
\newline
\ac{owasp} is another organization.
\newline
\ac{iso} is yet another organization.
\newline
\ac{cicd} is a good practice in software development.

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acronyms}
\printacronyms[name=Acronyms]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `itemsep` (from `enumitem` package) to the length you desire before `\printacronyms`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{acro} %list of abbreviations
\acsetup{first-style = long-short, list/display = used}

\DeclareAcronym{acm}{ 
    short = {ACM}, 
    long  = {Association for Computing Machinery}
}
\DeclareAcronym{ieee}{
    short = {IEEE},
    long  = {Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers}
}

\DeclareAcronym{owasp}{ 
    short = {OWASP}, 
    long  = {the Open Web Application Security Project}
}

\DeclareAcronym{iso}{ 
    short = {ISO}, 
    long  = {International Organization for Standardization}
}

\DeclareAcronym{cicd} {
    short = {CI/CD}, 
    long = {the combined practices of continuous integration and continuous delivery or continuous deployment}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Showcases of acro Acronyms}

\ac{ieee} is an organization.
\newline
\ac{acm} is another organization.
\newline
\ac{owasp} is another organization.
\newline
\ac{iso} is yet another organization.
\newline
\ac{cicd} is a good practice in software development.

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acronyms}
\setlist{itemsep=5ex}\printacronyms[name=Acronyms]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @CarLaTex, thank you very much for your solution! I tested it and the output looked nice! However, I have a long entry "cicd" (I edited my original question to include this entry), I'd like the line-wrap within an entry having single line spacing, but not double. Do you maybe know how to achieve this?

Comment: @NicoleNaumann Of course, see my renewed answer.